# How to put complex into a numpy's array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.zeros((3,3))
>>> A[0,0] = 9
>>> A
array([[ 9.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> A[0,1] = 1+2j
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
>>> A[0,1] = np.complex(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

According to my example code. i tried to put complex number into the numpy's array but it didn't work. May be i miss some basic thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to create an array containing complex values, you need to specify a complex type to numpy:

```
>>> A = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=complex)

>>> print A
[[ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]]

>>> A[0,0] = 1. + 2.j

>>> print A
[[ 1.+2.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the array's type.

**Example:**

```
>>> from numpy import array, dtype
>>> A = array([1, 2, 3])
>>> A[0] = 1+2j
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to long
>>> B = A.astype(dtype("complex128"))
>>> B[0] = 1+2j
>>> B
array([ 1.+2.j,  2.+0.j,  3.+0.j])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment on [talonmies's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24303244/15124881) (and the suggested edit queue is full), so I have to put this here.

`np.complex` is getting deprecated, so you'll want to just set `dtype=complex`

Here's the deprecation listing in their version 1.20.0 release notes: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.20.0-notes.html?highlight=complex#deprecations

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29964923)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).